# estimateSize() on sequential Spliterator

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream, spliterator

I'm implementing a `Spliterator` that explicitly restricts parallelization by having `trySplit()` return `null`. Would implementing `estimateSize()` offer any performance improvements for a stream produced by this spliterator? Or is the estimated size only useful for parallelization?

**EDIT:** To clarify, I'm specifically asking about an *estimated* size. In other words, my spliterator does not have the `SIZED` characteristic.

Comment: At least the toArray method will use estimated sizes; a reasonably accurate estimate may reduce copying.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Looking at the call hierarchy to the relevant spliterator characteristic reveals that it's at least relevant for `stream.toArray()` performance

[image]

Additionally there is an equivalent flag in the internal stream implementation that seems to be used for sorting:

[image]

So aside from parallel stream operations the size estimate seems to be used  for those two operations.

I don't claim exhaustiveness for my search, so just take these as examples.

---

Without the SIZED characteristic I can only find calls to `estimateSize()` that are relevant to parallel execution of the stream pipeline.

Of course this might change in the future or another Stream implementation than the standard JDK one could act differently.

Comment: Clarified my question a bit.

Comment: in that case it only seems to be used for parallel execution

Comment: Well, the most important sentences is the last one: “*Of course this might change in the future or another Stream implementation than the standard JDK one could act differently*”, which deserves a +1. It should also be noted that other libraries might also access the `Spliterator` directly and gain advantage of such a feature. That’s why it’s always recommended to program against the *contract*, not the current implementation.

Comment: @holger There's no *requirement* to provide an estimated size. I'm not going to make my API more complicated if I don't expect any benefit in my use case.

Comment: @shmosel: there is no requirement but an opportunity. Of course, if estimating a size implies more work to you, don’t do it. That’s the whole point of *estimate*Size, you *may* provide it if it’s cheap to guess.

Comment: @Holger I would happily implement a size estimate if it were up to me, but unfortunately, the only one that can do that is the client of my spliterator/stream. Obviously I want to avoid any unnecessary complication to the client.

Answer (score 0):

A spliterator may traverse elements:

1.Individually([tryAdvance()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Spliterator.html#tryAdvance-java.util.function.Consumer-))

2.Sequentially in bulk([forEachRemaining()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Spliterator.html#forEachRemaining-java.util.function.Consumer-))

As per [java docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Spliterator.html#estimateSize--) `estimateSize()` comes handy during splitting.

> Spliterators can provide an estimate of the number of remaining
>   elements via the estimateSize() method. Ideally, as reflected in
>   characteristic SIZED, this value corresponds exactly to the number of
>   elements that would be encountered in a successful traversal. **However,
>   even when not exactly known, an estimated value value may still be
>   useful to operations being performed on the source, such as helping to
>   determine whether it is preferable to split further or traverse the
>   remaining elements sequentially**.

Since your spliterator does not have the SIZED characteristic  `estimateSize` will not offer any performance(because of no parallelism ), However keep in mind that Java-docs of `estimateSize` doesn't mention anything of parallelism ,all it states is:

> Returns: the estimated size, or Long.MAX_VALUE if infinite, unknown,
>   or too expensive to compute.

Comment: The only example given in the bold section is about determining if it's preferrable to split further. And splitting is only used on parallel streams, which the OP rejects explicitely, hence the question.